# How to set an if condition for the json data sent to android via PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I have a PHP file which gets data from a MySQL database and sends it to android as a json array. As for now, all the rows are sent to the android app. I want to send only the rows where the `approved` value is 1. How can I do this? I tried

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) && ($row['approved']==1))
```

but it doesn't work. Here's my PHP file

```
<?php

//Create Database connection

$db = mysql_connect("localhost","shareity","sh@r31tymysql");

if (!$db) {

    die('Could not connect to db: ' . mysql_error());

}


//Select the Database

mysql_select_db("shareity",$db);



//Replace * in the query with the column names.

$result = mysql_query("select * from event", $db); 



//Create an array

$json_response = array();



while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {

    $row_array['eid'] = $row['eid'];

    $row_array['ename'] = $row['ename'];

    $row_array['etype'] = $row['etype'];

    $row_array['edesc'] = $row['edesc'];

    $row_array['esdate'] = $row['esdate'];

    $row_array['eedate'] = $row['eedate'];

    $row_array['estime'] = $row['estime'];

    $row_array['eetime'] = $row['eetime'];

    $row_array['location'] = $row['location'];

    $row_array['created_at'] = $row['created_at'];

    $row_array['edited_at'] = $row['edited_at'];

    $row_array['createdby'] = $row['createdby'];

    $row_array['approved'] = $row['approved'];




    //push the values in the array

    array_push($json_response,$row_array);

}

//echo json_encode($json_response);
echo json_encode(array('events'=>$json_response));


//Close the database connection

fclose($db);
```

?>

Comment: Your SQL query doesn't set any filtering criteria so naturally - if that information is in one of the columns of the `event` table - you will get approved and non-approved events. Try something like this instead: `SELECT * FROM event WHERE event.approved = 1`.

Comment: I added this `if($row['approved']==1){` inside the while loop and it works. Thanks for your comment @nhee, it works too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just after your while loop, add an if and continue when the row does not match your condition:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {
      if ($row['approved'] != 1)
           continue; // We don't want to have any rows that are not approved.
      // code...
 }
```

Alternatively, you could choose to limit your SQL query so only approved rows are retrieved.

```
 $result = mysql_query("select * from event where `approved` = 1", $db);
```